Install Chrome Driver in Airflow Docker Image
I need to install chrome driver in airflow image. This is the command I use :
# Use the base image
FROM apache/airflow
USER root
# Install necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libasound2 \
        libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
        libgtk-4-1 \
        libnss3 \
        xdg-utils \
        wget && \
    wget -q -O chrome-linux64.zip https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.85/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip && \
    unzip chrome-linux64.zip && \
    rm chrome-linux64.zip && \
    mv chrome-linux64 /opt/chrome/ && \
    ln -s /opt/chrome/chrome /usr/local/bin/

# Run a command that keeps the container running
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]


However, I get this error when I try to build the image:
#5 50.69 W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bullseye InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
#5 50.69 W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
#5 50.69 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
#5 50.72 Reading package lists...
#5 52.07 Building dependency tree...
#5 52.54 Reading state information...
#5 52.78 E: Unable to locate package libgtk-4-1
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -o errexit -o nounset -o nolog -c apt-get update -qq -y &&     apt-get install -y         libasound2         libatk-bridge2.0-0         libgtk-4-1         libnss3         xdg-utils         wget &&     wget -q -O chrome-linux64.zip https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.85/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip &&     unzip chrome-linux64.zip &&     rm chrome-linux64.zip &&     mv chrome-linux64 /opt/chrome/ &&     ln -s /opt/chrome/chrome /usr/local/bin/ && CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]]: exit code: 100

I used --fix-missing, but it didn't help.
